# Most elegant or simple way to make a train follow a curve?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, bezier-curves, constraints

Rigging a train on a curve has it's problems. The cars have a fixed length and the tighter the radius of the curve, the more the car will cut corners. So a fixed offset will be too long.

My current solution is a bit convoluted:

[image: choo choo]

- I make empties track the main path.
- I control a helper curve with hooks so the helper curve fits the main path reasonably well. The more empties, the better.
- I use a Spline IK Constraint for the bones.

I do that because I cannot seem to move the IK constraint up or down the curve.

Is there a simpler way? I could do it with Python and iterations, but I wonder whether there's an inbuilt method I have overlooked.

Comment: What about this method? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OM9Nso_ncEk

Comment: @Crantisz No idea. It's not an answer and I have 64kbit internet, so any attempt to watch it from here is futile.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consult the following Web page.
https://blenderartists.org/t/train-follows-track-whats-the-right-combo-of-constraints/531763 (2023-09.at)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/179631)